# Simple HTML DOM Parser error

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get e-mail addresses from 10.000+ pages.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://www.myurl');
$email = $html->find('dl', 5)->children(3);
```

Sometimes get the follow error. Probably because some page's don't have the  tag:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object
```

How to avoid this error if a page doesn't contain the info I'm looking for without interrupting the complete script?

Comment: The `find()` failed to locate anything, so what it returns has no ->children() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test to see if `$email` is an object by using the `is_object()` function, e.g.

```
$email = $html->find('dl', 5);
if(is_object($email) === true)
{
    print_r($email->children(3));
}
else continue;
```

This would probably be quicker than testing for children using an external library since it uses a function already present in the PHP engine.

Answer (score 2):

Don't chain your methods if there's uncertainty. Assign `$email = $html->find('dl', 5)` - then test if there are any children, probably with [`hasChildNodes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php)